# How to catch the "terminated" event for each subprocess in Java joined threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have "n" threads "joined" and I would like to know when each thread ends.

I wrote this code, but the states I get are "RUNNABLE, TIMED_WAITING, etc." but not "FINISHED". That would be expected to be thrown (at least) by the "finish" thread.

```java
       for (index = 0; index < MAX_ITEMS; index++){                  
            try {
                pan = panes[index];

                ThreadAmasar amasar = new ThreadAmasar(pan, tc);
                ThreadPreparar preparar = new ThreadPreparar(pan, tc);
                ThreadHornear hornear = new ThreadHornear(pan, tc);
                ThreadFinish finish = new ThreadFinish(pan, tc);

                preparar.SetParent(amasar);
                hornear.SetParent(preparar);
                finish.SetParent(hornear);

                Thread.sleep(0);

                amasar.start();
                preparar.start();
                hornear.start();
                finish.start();

                //ThreadAmasar.State.TERMINATED

                 System.out.println( pan.Nombre +  " A > " + amasar.getState());
                 System.out.println( pan.Nombre +  " P > " + preparar.getState());
                 System.out.println( pan.Nombre +  " H > " + hornear.getState());
                 System.out.println( pan.Nombre +  " F > " + finish.getState());


                System.out.println("Estableciendo tarea " + pan.Nombre);
                System.out.println("");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadHacerPan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error interno:" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

the previous code is executed into "run" method of thread "HacerPan" and this my log results:

```
> Inicio: Thu Oct 11 11:27:53 CDT 2018
>>> Proceso iniciado:Thu Oct 11 11:27:53 CDT 2018
Pan 9 A > RUNNABLE
Pan 9 P > RUNNABLE
Pan 9 F > RUNNABLE
Pan 9 > Amasando... tiempo: 5000
Estableciendo tarea Pan 9

>>> Proceso iniciado:Thu Oct 11 11:27:53 CDT 2018
Pan 8 A > RUNNABLE
Pan 8 P > RUNNABLE
Pan 8 F > RUNNABLE
Estableciendo tarea Pan 8

>>> Proceso iniciado:Thu Oct 11 11:27:53 CDT 2018
Pan 8 > Amasando... tiempo: 30000
Pan 2 > Amasando... tiempo: 28000
Pan 2 A > TIMED_WAITING
Pan 2 P > RUNNABLE
Pan 2 F > RUNNABLE
Estableciendo tarea Pan 2 Pan 9 --> RUNNABLE
Pan 9 > Preparando...  tiempo: 13000
Pan 9 > Horneando... tiempo: 22000
Pan 2 --> RUNNABLE
Pan 2 > Preparando...  tiempo: 21000
Pan 8 --> RUNNABLE
Pan 8 > Preparando...  tiempo: 19000
Pan 9 cocinado!!!
```

How is the correct way to catch the "terminated" event for each thread?

Sorry for the omission, the class code for the threads "Amasar", "Preparar", "Hornear" and "Finish" is this:

```
public class ThreadHornear extends Thread {
    private Pan pan;
    private Thread parent;
    private ThreadCounter tc;

    public ThreadHornear (Pan pan, ThreadCounter tc){
        this.pan = pan;
        this.tc = tc;
    }

    public void SetParent(Thread parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            if ( parent != null){
                parent.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ThreadAmasar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is when "join" the threads.

Comment: `join` the thread(s)..? From the code it does not appear valid to assume that the threads have finished/terminated prior to accessing the state.

Comment: @user2864740, Do you know a way to set a handler to "terminated" event of thread?

Comment: Consider using a `CountDownLatch` for each iteration, where each thread calls the shared `latch.countDown()` as the last instruction, and the main thread running the loop has `latch.await()`.

Comment: An interrupt is an explicit request to stop what you are doing, and exit cleanly.  When you catch InterruptedException, the correct course of action is to exit your loop, not just log the exception and ignore it.  An even better approach is placing your entire loop inside the try/catch.  If you just ignore interrupts, you are writing a rogue thread.

Comment: @AndrewS, I have a code in which the main thread executes "n" second level threads (tasks), and this executes "x" threads "joined" (activities), can I use CountDownLatch for each "task"?.

Comment: @VGR, Each "pan" I visualize as a task, and each thread ("amasar", "preparar", "hornear" and "finish"), are activities.
The final idea of ​​the code will be to process task by task and record the progress of each activity, and write in the log regardless of whether it was an interruption, validation or unexpected error.

I hope I do not have a wrong approach.

Comment: @Janhell The 'handler' is when `join` returns successfully.. guard using the appropriate semaphore as desired, but one *should* `join` terminated threads. After a thread is joined is *guaranteed* to be terminated. There is no event raised, although one *could* write [another] thread to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the “terminated” event by using `Future` or `FutureTask` class.
The following code is an example of `FutureTask`.

```
public class HowToCatchTerminatedEvent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            System.out.println("run....");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        },1);
        Thread th = new Thread(futureTask);
        //NEW
        System.out.println(th.getState());
        th.start();
        //RUNNABLE
        System.out.println(th.getState());

        //blocked until the th thread done
        System.out.println(futureTask.get());
        //TERMINATED
        System.out.println(th.getState());
    }
}
```